# how to use a wordpress blog theme on a django-based website

Tags: django, django-cms

I've built a website using django, and now I want to build a blog for my website at url domain.com/blog. I need to create it in wordpress and then import it to django, using the wordpress theme.

The different solutions I found on the web are to import the data from WP to django, but how do I use the WP theme in my django template? or do I have to make my own templates (which I don't want)?

Also, should I use wordpress in the first place(its SEO pluggins are quite strong) or should I use a django blogging app instead?

very confused about it, any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Your first paragraph is confusing, the second is puzzling, you lost me completely on the third.. Django is not wordpress, you could rewrite an url to a wordpress/php process in your server but you can't (well shouldn't) mix either of these separate processes. If your goal is to migrate Wordpress blog logic and templates to a Django project you will have to write the app and templates yourself and perhaps copy some css.

Comment: Thanks for the response! all I wanted was to use a wordpress blog on a django website. I got it working by integrating it with WP (and php), here's what I did - added the alias /blog in my config file. This tells apache not to redirect this url request to django. Then I installed phpMyAdmin on the server, placed the blog directory that I got from wordpress in my project. So now when I open domain.com/blog, it opens up the blog thats made in wordpress.

Answer (score 11):

> how do I use the WP theme in my django template?

You have to extract the base HTML/CSS/JS(without any PHP code) and use them to *create* a Django template. No other way.

> or do I have to make my own templates (which I don't want)?

You have to. Wordpress is a PHP framework and it's templates are incompatible with Django, which is a Python framework.

> Also, should I use wordpress in the first place(its SEO pluggins are quite strong) or should I use a django blogging app instead?

Questions that start with *Should* always have controversial answers. You should research and choose what you need. No one is here to research for others.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try your solution as I thought making my own template would be a bit of a lengthy process. I installed php on my server and imported the WP blog to my django app.